# Como melhorar um código de classificação por estrelas?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou com um site e certos pontos me prendem, como esse de avaliação, não está muito legal esse *script*, alguém apto pode melhorar para mim ou me falar o que pode melhorar, para deixar o código mais organizado, verificar se o usuário selecionou alguma estrela, dar mensagem de erro

Códigos:

```
$star1 = isset($_POST["star1"]);
$star2 = isset($_POST["star2"]);
$star3 = isset($_POST["star3"]);
$star4 = isset($_POST["star4"]);
$star5 = isset($_POST["star5"]);

if ($star1 == 1)
{
    $star = $_POST["star1"];
}
if ($star2 == 1)
{
    $star = $_POST["star2"];
}
if ($star3 == 1)
{
    $star = $_POST["star3"];
}
if ($star4 == 1)
{
    $star = $_POST["star4"];
}
if ($star5 == 1)
{
    $star = $_POST["star5"];
}
```

Uso a variavel **$star** para fazer o *INSERT* dos pontos que o usuário selecionou, mais se ele não seleciona nada envia '0' para a DB.

Aqui está as estrelas:

```
<div class="rating_star">
                <div id="col_star">
                    <table cellspacing=2 cellpadding="2">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="48" onmouseover="rate('1')" onmouseout="retira('1')" onclick="rating('1');">
                                <img id="1" src="../img/star_48x48.png" border="0" id="star1" style="cursor:pointer;width:48px;">
                            </td>
                            <td width="48" onmouseover="rate('2')" onmouseout="retira('2')" onclick="rating('2');">
                                <img id="2" src="../img/star_48x48.png" border="0" id="star2" style="cursor:pointer;width:48px;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="48" onmouseover="rate('3')" onmouseout="retira('3')" onclick="rating('3');">
                                <img id="3" src="../img/star_48x48.png" border="0" id="star3" style="cursor:pointer;width:48px;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="48" onmouseover="rate('4')" onmouseout="retira('4')" onclick="rating('4');">
                                <img id="4" src="../img/star_48x48.png" border="0" id="star4" style="cursor:pointer;width:48px;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="48" onmouseover="rate('5')" onmouseout="retira('5')" onclick="rating('5');">
                                <img id="5" src="../img/star_48x48.png" border="0" id="star5" style="cursor:pointer;width:48px;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td id="note" width="65"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>              
                </div>
                <div id="msg"></div>
```

E aqui o script que faz tudo funcionar:

```
<script>
    function cache() 
    {
        imagens = new Image();
        imagens.src='../img/star_48x48.png';
        imagens.src='../img/star1_48x48.png';
    }

    function rate(id)
    {
        if(id==1)
        {
        document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star1' id='star1' value='1'></font>";
        }
        if(id==2)
        {
        document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star2' id='star2' value='2'></font>";
        }
        if(id==3)
        {
        document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star3' id='star3' value='3'></font>";
        }
        if(id==4)
        {
        document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star4' id='star4' value='4'></font>";
        }
        if(id==5)
        {
        document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star5' id='star5' value='5'></font>";
        }
        for(i = 0; i < id; i++)
        {
        document.getElementById(i+1).src="../img/star1_48x48.png";
        }
    }

    function retira(id) 
    {
        for(i = 5; i > id; i--) 
        {
        document.getElementById(i).src="../img/star_48x48.png";
        }
    }

    function rating(id)
    {
        var user = document.getElementById('idLogged').value;

        if (user != "")
        {

        if(id==1) 
        {
            document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>Detestei</div>";
        }

        if(id==2) 
        {
            document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>Não gostei</div>";
        }

        if(id==3) 
        {
            document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-warning' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>Razoável</div>";
        }

        if(id==4) 
        {
            document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-info' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>Gostei</div>";
        }

        if(id==5) 
        {
            document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-success' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>Adorei</div>";
        }       
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'><strong>Erro ao avaliar!</strong> É necessário realizar o login para enviar um comentário.</div>";
        }
    }
</script>
```

E então, está meio ruim esse sistema não está?

Se o usuário não seleciona as estrela consegue cadastrar '0'

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

A primeira coisa que eu faria é o seguinte:

```
for ($i = 4; $i > 0; $i--) {
     if (isset($_POST["star" . $i])) {
         $star = $_POST["star" . $i];
         break;
     }
}
```

No HTML basicamente só economizaria na indentação. Também poderia usar `<div>` no lugar de usar uma `<table>`, isto é estilo antigo e errado.

Se ele puder ser gerado automaticamente, aí dá para melhorar. É muito código repetitivo, poderia criar um laço para gerar isto.

No JS capricharia mais na indentação e resolveria de outra forma o envio do dado. Não precisa de 5 variáveis, precisa de uma uma com a quantidade de estrelas:

```
document.getElementById('note').innerHTML="<font class='ajax'><input type='hidden' name='star' id='star' value='" + id + "'></font>";
for (var i = 0; i < id; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i + 1).src = "../img/star1_48x48.png";
}
```

Eu ainda tiraria esse `<font>`, isto é velho e não faz sentido neste caso.

Na verdade tenho minhas dúvidas se precisaria deste `for`. Mas está confuso demais para entender o objetivo.

Aí dá para melhorar o PHP para:

```
$star = $_POST["star"]; //na verdade nem precisa criar esta variável
```

Aí vai ficar guardado o número de estrelas que é a informação mais relevante.

Na outra função do JS:

```
var textos = ["Detestei", "Não gostei", "Razoável", "Gostei", "Adorei"];
var user = document.getElementById('idLogged').value;
if (user != "") {
    document.getElementById('voto').value = id;
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'>" + texxtos[id - 1] + "</div>";
} else {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:48px;text-align:center;'><strong>Erro ao avaliar!</strong> É necessário realizar o login para enviar um comentário.</div>";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Stars.js).

Não estou analisando se o código está certo, só reescrevendo. Nem dá sem conhecer todo o código. Como não tem um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), não tenho como testar se as alterações estão todas certas. Em um contexto maior é provável que dê para melhorar outras coisas. Dá pinta. Mas eu não posso fazer o código inteiro de novo para você. Aí tem as ideias básicas, basta aproveitar.

Comment: Como faço pra verificar se o usuário selecionou alguma estrela ?

Comment: Eu não posso dizer com certeza, não vi todo o código, não tenho como testar. De fato isto não está solucionado no código.

Comment: aqui faltou um ' $ ' star = $_POST["star" . $i]; neh ?

Comment: É, faltou mesmo. Ainda estou melhorando algumas coisas.